# How to return a value from nested lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, nested, inline

I'm trying to create a function that returns location in a lambda expression.

I know, I could simply put the return type to the parameter list and get the location that way, but I want this method to be used by other methods contained in a class that doesn't have reference to an activity, so I'd simply save this lambda as a property and use it that way.

Although I can't find a way to do that, because the only label I can specify in task result after invoking lastLocation is return@success and return@failure, which returns Unit.

I guess it has something to do with inlined functions, but I haven't found a way to implement it. Any ideas how to do that? Or should I rather look for different approach?

```
fun getLastLocation(activity: Activity): () -> Location? = function@{

    if (!checkPermission(activity)) {
        requestPermissions(activity)
        return@function null
    }

    if (!isLocationEnabled(activity)) {
        redirectToSettings(activity)
        return@function null
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.apply {
        initiate {
            success { location -> // Success listener
                if (location == null)
                    Log.e(TAG, "getLastLocation: Retrieved location is null")

                // return@function location  // Return not allowed here
            }

            failure { e -> // Failure listener
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: getLastLocation() failed")
                e.printStackTrace()

                // return@function null // Return not allowed here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You _can't_ do this normally -- not, at least, without coroutines.  You can't have your function wait for a listener to get called and then return that value.

Comment: What are `initiate`/`success`/`failure` here?  It looks like some kind of callback — which could be why it can't return from the top-level lambda, as it could be called after that lambda has finished.  If so, I guess you'll either have to make it synchronous by waiting for the result (and perhaps storing it in the callback somewhere it can be retrieved by the top-level lambda), or making the top-level lambda asynchronous too and giving _that_ callbacks.

Comment: Yes, I see why it didn't work. So the solution would be to make it asynchronous, but I'd better try to redesign my code and move the return type to the parameter list, so it's a normal Unit function and return a result that way.